# Customizing the xml serialization of a DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable, schema

I have a data table that contains the below information.

[image]

I want to write this data table to xml, so I used the `WriteXml` method, that produced the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person1</Name>
    <Contact>Fred Nurk</Contact>
    <CourseName>Course 1</CourseName>
    <CourseTime>09:00</CourseTime>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person1</Name>
    <Contact>Fred Nurk</Contact>
    <CourseName>Course 2</CourseName>
    <CourseTime>10:00</CourseTime>
  </Person>
</DocumentElement>
```

I want to the xml to combine the courses of the same person so that the xml will look like the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Person>
    <name>Person1</name>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
      <Courses>
        <Course>
          <courseName>Course 1</courseName>
          <courseTime>09:00</courseTime>
        </Course>
        <Course>
          <courseName>Course 2</courseName>
          <courseTime>10:00</courseTime>
        </Course>
      </Courses>    
  </Person>
</DocumentElement>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why i got a -1, please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to copy your data to a temp-table with the columns

```
<name> <contact> <coursename1> <coursetime1> <coursename2> <coursetime2> <coursenameX> <coursetimeX> <coursenameX> <coursetimeX> <..and so on>
```

and write this to XML

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case you should implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and make your xml as you want

implement the methods

```
public XmlSchema GetSchema()
{
    return null; //this should remain equal
}

public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    //group your list of Person as you want then
    foreach (Person person in list)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Persons");
        person.WriteXml(writer);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

in `WriteXml` function you can check for each element if the person is already in the xml (add only the course) or not (add the entire node)